# Accessing a websites home file without the file name and extension

Tags: apache, http, url, url-routing

I am working on a website that has a URL such as the following:

```
http://www.domain.com/directory/home.php
```

I was wondering if it is possible to set up the site so users can access it like so:

```
http://www.domain.com/directory/
```

And the browser will automatically find and render the home.php file?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm assuming you are using `Apache`, please retag in case you are using something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `Apache`, from the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex):

> The DirectoryIndex directive sets the list of resources to look for,
>   when the client requests an index of the directory by specifying a /
>   at the end of the directory name. Local-url is the (%-encoded) URL of
>   a document on the server relative to the requested directory; it is
>   usually the name of a file in the directory. Several URLs may be
>   given, in which case the server will return the first one that it
>   finds. If none of the resources exist and the Indexes option is set,
>   the server will generate its own listing of the directory.

Add this to the `httpd.conf` file :

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

Then to remove the `.php` from the URLs, add this to the `.htaccess` file in the root folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there a way to accomplish this while using a shared apache server? I don't have access to the `httpd.conf` file, because I am not using a dedicated server.

Comment: I've not tried it, but you could try adding `DirectoryIndex home.php` to the `.htaccess`, it should work